# If a field of a sub class hides a field of the same name of the super class, what exactly happens with both fields internally?

Tags: java

If I hide the field of a super class by declaring the same field with the same name in the sub class, what happens with the super class field internally. Say, I have the field

```
class Animal{
    String name = "Peter";
}
```

in the super class and then declare the field

```
class Dog extends Animal{
    String name = "Sigmund";
}
```

in the sub class. If I instantiate the sub class I can access the super class field by typecasting to the super class. I understand the concept of hiding fields vs overriding methods, but how is the hidden field represented internally in the memory? Does my sub class object have two fields of the same name, one with the String "Peter" and one with the String "Sigmund"?

Here a simple code example:

```
class Animal{
    String name = "Peter";
}

class Dog extends Animal{
    String name = "Sigmund";
}
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Animal a = new Dog();

        System.out.println(a.name); // -> Peter
        System.out.println(((Dog)a).name);  //-> Sigmund
    }
}
```

Comment: In my mind they are two different and independent member variables since variables can't be overridden. So your memory consumption would increase in this case.

Comment: Nothing 'happens' to the field.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson

I had the same thought, but I cannot directly access the super class field from within the the sub class, at least not without typecasting so I'm rather interested how this is handled internally, say within the memory.

Comment: @DesMondesBlut No, you can access it within the super class by using `super.name` (unless it is private, which it isn't in your exanple).

Comment: @Dorian Gray Ah, right. So the field "name" of the subclass "Dog" is indeed a completely different field and the field "name" from the super class is inherited but due to the same field name it cannot be directly accessed? So in case of an equal field name the compiler just "picks" the field of the reference type? Is that the correct assumption?

Comment: No, it is not inherited, it's hidden. Only methods are inherited. The whole point of hiding smth is that you cannot see it directly.

Comment: I see... But if I didn't declare the field in the sub class the field "name" from the super class would be inherited and I could access the field from the super class normally. So if I don't want a sub class to inherit a field I explicitly hide it by declaring it in the sub class right? But in what case would that make sense?

Comment: Well, no, if you don't want your subclass to see a field from a super class, mark it as private. Hiding members is generally not recommended, as it leads to confusion and even dispair.

Comment: @DorianGray I'm not sure what that means--hiding members is *totally* recommended if it represents data that other classes, or other subclasses, aren't allowed to modify. It's one of the basic tenets of Java-style OOP: only expose what is explicitly meant to be exposed.

Comment: @DaveNewton Dorian Gray is talking about the technical term of hiding as described in this question (non-private fields with the same name), not about "hiding" as in "make it private to hide it".

Comment: @Progman Ah, I see. Yes, if hiding like this ever seems necessary then there's likely a missing method or other abstraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an object of `Animal`, memory will be allocated to hold the values or references of all the fields the `Animal` class has, regardless of the visibility used. So in this case, memory is allocated for a `String` reference, which is identified with the name of the field `name`.

When you create an object of `Dog`, memory will be allocated to hold the values or references of all the fields the `Dog` class has as well as all the fields of the `Animal` class, regardless of the visibility used. This means when you create an object of your `Dog` class, you will have a field `name`, defined by the `Animal` class, which reference the String "Peter" and you will have a different field `name`, defined by the `Dog` class, which reference the String "Sigmund".

Which field is read/written when used depends on the context and what types the compiler is seeing. When you write

```
Animal a = ...;
... a.name ...;
```

the compiler will use the `name` field from the `Animal` class. When you write

```
Dog d = ...
... d.name ...;
```

the compiler use the one from the `Dog` class.

To answer your question: Yes, both fields are present in the memory.